# Making an array of pointer to classes

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am trying to make an Array which will contain pointer to a class.
The size of the array will be given from keyboard , so i tried to create the array with the following way :

```
 class creature
 {
    protected:
      string crt_name ;
      int L ;   
    public:
       creature( int Life = -1 , string Name = "")
        : L(Life) , crt_name(Name){} 

       string get_crt_name ( void )
       { 
          return crt_name ;
       }
 }; 

 class creature_society
 {
    private:
       creature* *A ;
       int noc ;
    public:
       creature_society( int , int ) ;
       ~creature_society() ;
       creature** get_A ( void ){return A ;}
 };
```

The constructor of creature society will fill the array with creatures made randomly

```
creature_society::creature_society( int life , int number_of_creatures )
{
   noc =  number_of_creatures ;
   A = new creature*[noc] ;

   creature* temporary ;

   for( int  i = 0 ; i<= number_of_creatures -1 ; i++)
   {
     if ( rand()%100 <= 50) 
        {
            temporary = new good_creature( life , get_unique_name( 3 ) );
            A[i] = temporary ;
        }
        else
        {
            temporary = new bad_creature( life , get_unique_name( 3 ) );
            A[i] = temporary ;
        }
  }
}
```

Then I try to print the array

```
    cout << endl << "Printing Society:" << endl ;
    for ( j = 0 ; j <= N -1 ; j++)
    {
       temp = (*( cs1.get_A() + j ))->get_crt_name() ;
    }
```

The problem is that when i am getting segmentation faults when running on linux , while working fine on Dev C++  ( most of the time )!
Any mistakes you pointed out ?

Comment: Are you opposed to `std::vector<creature*>`? It will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: @CoryKramer: Ew, why storage of raw pointers??

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Okay fine, even better would be `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<creature>>`. Baby steps :)

Comment: @CoryKramer: Let's not give the super-sharp axe to a baby, eh? :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit surely a raw pointer is the sharpest axe in the toolshed? Used only for the very hardest trees?

Comment: Post a complete buildable runnable program.

Comment: You also forgot to define a virtual destructor in `creature`

Comment: @RichardHodges: Yes, exactly.

Comment: Eh, why any ptr? std::vector<creature> is the way to do it. Since there is no virtual destructor in creature, there is no need for the pointer.

Comment: @SergeyA You'll notice they say `new good_creature` and `new bad_creature` later in the code. They'll [slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) if they store them that way.

Comment: @CoryKramer, and they will have a memory leak if they store it as a pointer to base...

Comment: @SergeyA Not if they use `std::unique_ptr` and the base class has a `virtual` destructor.

Comment: @CoryKramer, but there is none. I am talking about the code as written.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply do,

```
for (int j=0 ; j < N; ++j)
{
   temp = cs1.get_A()[j]->get_crt_name();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention here the classes of `bad_creature` and `good_creature`.
I assume they inherit creature as a base a class and therefore you should define `get_crt_name` as a virtual function.

Maybe something went wrong with your `get_unique_name` function as well.
I executed your code in VC2015 and no faulty was found (I replaced ofcourse `good creature` and `bad creature` classes with `creature` and that I replaced `get_unique_name` with a const string).

Please:

1.Check with your core dump where did your program crash.
2.What output it emitted before the segmentation fault.

For future, class names should always begin with uppercase letters as it is a very common style convention.

Comment: @CoryKramer I will edit my answer accordingly, though I really hate to encounter classes definitions starting with lowercase letters.. (unless they are from std of course)

Comment: I encounter a weird problem guys ,

Comment: @Social Programmer well, can't help if you don't write them down